# OpenLayers 3 Feature Layer Misplaced

Tags: openlayers

I am adding a feature layer of `ol.geom.Point` geometry as follows:

```
var location = result.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat.apply();
var lng = location.lng.apply();
var locationCoordinates = [lat, lng];
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(locationCoordinates, EPSG_3857, EPSG_4326)) });
vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
vectorLayer.setVisible(true);
var extent = vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

But the layer is misplaced, not exactly on longitude and latitude.

I am using EPSG:4326 projection, transforming Google Maps that's supposed to use EPSG:3857 projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries and searches to find a solution, I found this issue in OpenLayers repo on github:  [issue 2876](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2876).

When passing longitude and latitude to `ol.proj.transform([], string, string)`, you have to pass the parameters as follows: `[longitude, latitude]` not `[latitude, longitude]`. This is not even mentioned in the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#transform).